# Recursive checking a string for repeating pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

sorry if this is a duplicate but i couldnt find anything close.

i want to check recursively a string for the following pattern

```
[a-z0-9][:][a-z0-9][&][a-z0-9][:][a-z0-9]...
```

example

```
foo:bar&foo:bar1&foo:bar&foo:111&bar:2A2...
```

is it possible with regex and if so anyone can show me a regex expression for this?

If there is a efficient java method for this, it would be also good.

Comment: So you have to check if there are only letter and numbers in string and 1 : ?

Comment: Show us the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to match the whole string:

```
(\w+:\w+(?:&\w+:\w+)*)
```

See [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN7uX4/2).

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ey6dQS6nM5rrwkLf)

Comment: does "(..)+" means repeating?

Comment: `+` means match one or more times `?` means match zero or one time.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It depends on what exactly is supposed to be matched, but you may be right. I updated the answer.

Comment: **You should always use the second version**. The first version, if used with `String.matches` in Java, which asserts that the whole string has to match the regex, will match `foo:barfoo:bar1` https://regex101.com/r/fN7uX4/1

Comment: Another thing is that `\w` also matches capital letters and `_`, which is not in the original expression.

Comment: @nhahtdh Indeed, good catch. Concerning the capital letters, I assume that they are supposed to be matched, based on the sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the pattern inside a group with a preceding `&` and then make it to repeat zero or more times.

```
^[a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9]+(?:&[a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Anchors won't be needed if you use `matches` method.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iF6xI5/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match `value:value&` as a sole element multiple times,

```
(([a-z0-9]+:)([a-z0-9]+&))+
```

*NOTE : It won't match `value:value&value:`,`value&value&value:` etc.*